# How to convert signed doc with extensions .adoc or .edoc to pdf using command line?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, pdf

I need to convert signed .doc which have extensions .adoc or .edoc to PDF using the command line.

I have tried lowriter, soffice and unoconv but none of them seem to read these formats.

Is there any tool in ubuntu to convert .adoc and .edoc to PDF?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this [online utility](https://www.coolutils.com/online/ADOC-to-PDF) do this for you?

Comment: What do you mean by "signed .doc"? What is the output for `file *.adoc *.edoc` ?

Comment: I mean, as far as I know, that extensions .adoc and .edoc extensions are used for .doc files digitally signed